# Sum of SQL fields in PHP

Tags: php, zend-db

Hi I'm trying to find the sum of SQL fields in PHP. This sum must be
    less than or equal to the number which I receive in controller from
    JavaScript. But my SQL syntax is not working in PHP, instead it
    fetches all rows from the database.

```
public function feedbackaverageAction(){                
    $value =$_GET['value'];
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('dbadapter');
    $select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
    $select = $db->select();
    $select->from(array('feedback' => 'feedback'),
                   array ('customdata',
                          'checkinprocess',
                          'service_by_owner',
                          'locationrating',
                          'cleanlinessrating',
                          'valueformoneyrating',
                          'kitchenequipmentrating'));
    $select->where('feedback.checkinprocess' + 
                   'feedback.service_by_owner' + 
                   'feedback.locationrating' +
                   'feedback.cleanlinessrating' +
                   'feedback.valueformoneyrating' +
                   'feedback.kitchenequipmentrating' <= $value);
    $stmt = $select->query();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $this->view->rows = $result;
}
```

Can anyone help me how to find the sum and check it to the value which I got in the controller.

Comment: The concatination operator in PHP is "." (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and not "+". So if you want to do the math in SQL you have to use Zend_Db_Expr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and make SQL query like this.

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
$db = Zend_Registry::get('dbadapter');
$select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$select = $db->select();

$select->from(array('feedback' => 'feedback'),array ('customdata','checkinprocess','service_by_owner','locationrating','cleanlinessrating','valueformoneyrating','kitchenequipmentrating'));

$select->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('feedback.checkinprocess'+'feedback.service_by_owner'+'feedback.locationrating'+'feedback.cleanlinessrating'+'feedback.valueformoneyrating'+'feedback.kitchenequipmentrating')<= $value);

$stmt = $select->query();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$this->view->rows = $result;
```

Comment: IT is still taking all the rows ,never satisfies the condition  :-(((((((((((

Comment: just try to print/echo your query using `echo $stmt;` and tell me what is the query ?

Comment: hi,I have achieved this  with if condition in for each loop.thank u for ur help..

Comment: foreach($result as $row){
              $ratingsum=$row['checkinprocess']+$row['service_by_owner']+$row['valueformoneyrating']+$row['locationrating']+$row['kitchenequipmentrating']+$row['cleanlinessrating'];

Comment: it continues here,if ($ratingsum <= 80){
                    $arrValues[] = array("customdata"=>$row['customdata'], 
                                      "checkinprocess"=>$row['checkinprocess'],
                                     "service_by_owner"=>$row['service_by_owner'],"valueformoneyrating"=>$row['valueformoneyrating'],....]);}}
    $this->view->arrValues = $arrValues;                                  
                           
                    }
              }